# ICS Keyboard Source Code

Tags: java, android

Im trying to build somthing over a mature keyboard i tried sample softkeyboard but its just not that satisfying.
does anyone know where i can find the icescream sandwich keyboard source? or any mature keyboard with suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Android ICS source code from:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

From there you should be able to grep through and find the source code for the keyboard.

Comment: being even more specific https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME